# Is there a way to declare locally-scoped const in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, constants, visibility

It would be useful sometimes to have a locally scoped const i.e.

Example:

```
let process = () => {
  // local constant needed here:
  const let COUNT = 5; // notice: const let generates an error
  ...
}
```

Why? If you use normal const the "COUNT" will be visible out of the arrow function "process" and it is not desirable here.

Comment: Please attach a code snippet of the mentioned behaviour.

Comment: `const` is already local scope. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const): **Constants are block-scoped, much like variables defined using the let statement.**.

Comment: Use `const` or `let`, not both.

Comment: You should post your edit as an answer and self-accept it

Comment: @MEE It should just be closed, since the problem he's asking a solution for doesn't exist in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Okay then. It looks like *const* is already block-scoped so there's no need for additional effort (like it is with var and let).

```
let process = () => {
  // local constant needed here:
  const COUNT = 5;
  ...
}

// So here, out of the "process" block COUNT is not defined (ref to it throws Uncaught ReferenceError)
```

Thanks CRise

Question should be closed!